# How to download pre-trained models from Gluonnlp through a proxy?

Tags: proxy, mxnet, bert-language-model

I am behind a corporate proxy. I am trying to download BERT's vocabulary.

```py
_, vocab_bert = gluonnlp.model.bert_12_768_12(dataset_name='wiki_multilingual_uncased',
                                         pretrained=False, root='./model')
```

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apache-mxnet.s3-accelerate.dualstack.amazonaws.com', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: 
/gluon/dataset/vocab/wiki_multilingual_uncased-2b2514cc.zip 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x7f43c2650b38>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

How can provide my proxy data to gluonnlp in my Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set up the proxy in my Jupyter notebook:

```py
import os 
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://user:password01ge@proxy.com:8080/"  
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "https://user:password01ge@proxy.com:8080/"
```